# How to know whether two directories in google drive is the same

Tags: google-drive-api

I have two google drive account.
How to know whether a directory in the first account = a  directory in the second account?

definition of two directories being the same:
file contents are equivalent and the tree hierarchy is the same.

Comment: Well seeing as we have a synonym for Google-drive that turns it into Google-drive-api your response doesnt help much.   please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: After i know what your doing I would be interested in knowing How would you like to define the "same",  same title? same contents? same file id?  shared with the two accounts?

Answer (score 0):

existing problem:

- 1. `populate_tree_recursively_dict` need to run > 2 days if your google drive is huge
- 2. you get nothing if an error occurs while running
- 3. assume that the same name will imply the same file or same folder

```py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

def get_folder_id(root_folder_id, root_folder_title):
    file_list = get_children(root_folder_id)
    for file in file_list:
        if(file['title'] == root_folder_title):
            return file['id']
def get_children(root_folder_id):
    str = "\'" + root_folder_id + "\'" + " in parents and trashed=false"
    file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': str}).GetList()
    return file_list
def populate_tree_recursively_dict(tree,parent_id)
    if True: 
        print("now add tree")
        children = get_children(parent_id)

        if children:
            print("all children get, len",len(children))
            tree["child"]=[]
            for i in children:

                treeGetFromChild=populate_tree_recursively_dict({"title":i["title"]},i["id"])
                tree["child"].append(treeGetFromChild)
        else:
            print("no children")
        return tree


# first time auth to account A
gauth = GoogleAuth() 
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

root_folder_title = "folderNameInAccountA"  
root_folder_id = get_folder_id("root", root_folder_title)
preservedict={"heyhey":"root"}
a=populate_tree_recursively_dict(preservedict,root_folder_id)

# first time auth to account B
gauth = GoogleAuth() 
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

root_folder_title = "folderNameInAccountB"  
root_folder_id = get_folder_id("root", root_folder_title)
preservedict={"heyhey":"root"}
b=populate_tree_recursively_dict(preservedict,root_folder_id)

# compare 
import deepdiff
deepdiff.DeepDiff(a, b, ignore_order=True)
```